# Unable to change Applications Theme from settings :(

Tags: java, android, user-interface, themes, settings

Im having issue with setting a theme programmactally from changing a prefrence in the settings of the application i want to switch between Holo and Holo Light upon click the option in the settings.

Any recommendations, source code, knowledge, links etc are appreciated, thanks

---

### DashboardActivity.java

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_layout);

    if (Settings.theme.equals("Theme1")) {
        Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_LIGHT);

}else (Settings.theme.equals("Theme2")) {

    Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_DARK);

}
```

---

### Settings.java

```
     public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements  
          OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {   

 public static String theme = "Theme1";

    public void onBackPressed() {
    //  ListPreference listPreference2 = (ListPreference) findPreference("activityPref");
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("themePref");
        String currValue = listPreference.getValue();
    //  String currValue2 = listPreference.getValue();
//      Log.d("ssss", "Value :" + currValue);
    //  Log.d("ssss", "Value :" + currValue2);

    //  activity = currValue2;
        theme = currValue;
        super.onBackPressed();
```

### Settings.xml

```
   <ListPreference
            android:title="Themes"
            android:summary="Change the UI of the application"
            android:key="themePref"
            android:entries="@array/themesReturnValue"
            android:entryValues="@array/themesDisplayWord" 
            android:defaultValue="Theme1"/>
```

### Array.xml

```
    <string-array name="themesReturnValue">
    <item>Light</item>
    <item>Dark</item>

    </string-array>   
    <string-array name="themesDisplayWord">
    <item>Theme1</item>
    <item>Theme2</item>
```

### Styles

```
    <style name="LightThemeAndroid" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"> 
     </style>
   <style name="DarkThemeAndroid" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    </style>
```

Thats all i got.... I know its a task, however any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you get any help from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are vital parts of code missing, like `Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);` and `Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_LIGHT);` which could explain what is wrong/not working.

However, this is how I've solved it for my apps.

### settings.xml

```
<ListPreference
   android:title="@string/theme_label"
   android:summary="@string/theme_summary"
   android:key="@string/theme_key"
   android:defaultValue="0"
   android:entries="@array/theme_entries"
   android:entryValues="@array/theme_values" />
```

### strings.xml

```
<string name="theme_label">Theme</string>
<string name="theme_summary">Change the app theme</string>
<string name="theme_key">theme</string>
```

### arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="theme_entries" translatable="false">
   <item>Holo Light</item>
   <item>Holo Dark</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="theme_values" translatable="false">
   <item>0</item>
   <item>1</item>
</string-array>
```

### Util.java

```
public class Util extends Activity {

public static void setAppTheme(Activity a) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(a);
    int mTheme = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("theme", "0"));
    if (mTheme == 0) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                a.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar);
                return;
            }
            a.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
        }
        else {
            a.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        a.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
    } else {
        a.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black);
        }
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Util.setAppTheme(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```